# How to perform an operation to certain items in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a bit of code that generates a list of random numbers within a certain range (we'll say 0-100), but I would like for numbers that appear within a range (45-55) to not appear.

**For my specific purposes**, I would like to know how to add/subtract 11 to/from numbers that appear in that range. I wrote the line:

```
desired_list = [integer_list[i] - 11 for i in range(len(integer_list)) if integer_list[i] in list_of_consecutive_unwanted_integers]
```

But now when I print desired_list, it shows empty braces for about 4/5 times I retrieve the random numbers. No need to explain this strange phenomenon, but an explanation of what I did wrong and what I need instead would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
integer_list[i] in list_of_consecutive_unwanted_integers
```

checks whether the integer is unwanted, **discards** the ones not in the "unwanted list" and keeps the unwanted ones.

Here's how I'd solve this problem:

```
>>> # let's get 20 random integers in [0, 100]
>>> random_integers = (randint(0, 100) for _ in xrange(20))
>>> [x - 11 if 45 <= x <= 55 else x for x in random_integers]
[62, 0, 28, 34, 36, 96, 20, 19, 84, 17, 85, 83, 17, 91, 98, 33, 5, 100, 94, 97]
```

`x - 11 if 45 <= x <= 55 else x` is a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html) that subtracts 11 if the integer is in the range [45, 55]. You can also write this as

```
x - 11 * (45 <= x <= 55)
```

due to the fact that `True` and `False` have numeric values 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l    # Let l be the list of numbers in the range(0, 100) with some elements
[3, 4, 5, 45, 48, 6, 55, 56, 60]
>>> filter(lambda x: x < 45 or x > 55, l) # Remove elements in the range [45, 55]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 56, 60]
```

`filter` applies a function `f` to the input sequence and returns the items of the sequence for which f(item) returns `True`.

> **filter(...)**
>   filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string
>
> ```
> Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true. If
> function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a tuple
> or string, return the same type, else return a list.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
    >>> l = range(100)
    >>> [item for item in l if item <45 or item>55]
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```